# How Can i assign approval task to only one user?

Tags: approval

How can I assign an approval task to only one user and prevent any other users (even at the same permission level) from approving or rejecting this task even if they get the url of the Task Edit Form?

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a custom task or approval process in a Designer workflow, if you edit the task process, there's an option under settings to "Only allow task recipients and process owners to read and edit workflow tasks."

[image]

Comment: Sorry Miss.Erin L i am using Sharepoint Designer 2013 and i am beginer in this plateform ,  if i am not using Custom approval Process how can i complish that , this page dosent show for me

Comment: I'm not sure where this setting is in 2013

Comment: The Task Permissions Opition Dosn't Exist here 
i am using start a task Process Action And Assign this task to the HR manager and any user in the same level permission can approave the request

Comment: if creating custom task or approval process in workflow wll solve this problem , How can i create custom task ?

Comment: I have 2010. I tried to look it up, but I don't think there's a setting for it in 2013. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj614606.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Can i controll this permission in site permission level and stop inheriting permission and custom the permssion for users

Comment: You can use a workflow on the task list to set custom permissions on each task to match the "Assign to" field. It would have to run when the task is created and when it's saved, in case the task gets reassigned. You can only have 500 unique permissions on a site though. So if you break permissions on 501 tasks, or on 497 tasks and 3 lists, after that point it will stop working.

Comment: I just remembered that reassigning a task doesn't edit the task, rather, it creates a brand new one. So the permissions workflow would only need to run on create.